# Using cleveref with thesis template

Tags: cross-referencing, templates, cleveref

I am using the thesis template provided at LaTeX Templates http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis.

I would like to use the `cleveref` package for cross-referencing within my thesis.

I have tried inserting the package in the preamble with `\usepackage` and also tried putting it into the style file with `\requirepackage` but neither yields the correct result and I get `??` showing the `.pdf`.

Do you know where it should be inserted please? I notice in the package documentation it says the package must be loaded last.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Normally, it has to be inserted *after* `hyperref`, which itself should be loaded  as the last  package, with very few exceptions (cleveref is one of them).

Comment: You will always get `??` on the first compilation. You must compile at least twice (without deleting generated files).